# esp32 doesn't talk to chatbot

Tags: chatbot, esp32

The problem I am facing is the inability to get the Telegram bot, which was created to control an automatic dog feeder, to trigger a servo motor via the ESP32 microcontroller. Although the code compiles without errors, there is no response to the "/alimentar" command that should activate the servo to release the food. This is crucial for the functionality of the project, as it allows the pet owner to feed the animal remotely.
To be more specific, when the command is sent to the bot, the servo is expected to be triggered, which is not occurring. The servo should rotate, releasing a measured amount of food, but there seems to be a failure in communication between the bot and the ESP32, or a problem in the execution of the code that controls the servo. I have reviewed the physical connections and the program logic, but the error persists, and I am looking for alternative solutions or suggestions that may resolve this issue.
So far, I have tried running the code as described, expecting that, upon sending the "/alimentar" command via Telegram, the bot would respond with "Alimentando" and the servo motor would be triggered to release the food. The system has a mechanism that decreases a counter each time a portion of food is released, starting from 10. In addition, there are LEDs that indicate the number of remaining portions: if the counter is greater than or equal to 7, the green LED lights up; if it is greater than or equal to 4, the yellow LED lights up; and if it is less than 4, the red LED lights up, indicating that the portions are running low.
What I expected was that with each "/alimentar" command sent, in addition to the release of food, the counter would decrement by one, reflecting the amount of remaining portions through the indicative LEDs. However, the result has been that, although the Telegram bot responds with the message "alimentando", the servo is not activated and, consequently, there is no decrement in the counter, nor a change in the LED indicators. This suggests that the problem may lie in the servo activation logic or perhaps in some part of the communication between the bot and the ESP32 microcontroller.

This is my code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h>
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

Servo abridor; // cria o objeto servo

// GPIO de saída do servo
static const int servoPin = 13;
static const int verde = 35;
static const int amarelo = 34;
static const int vermelho = 33;

const char* ssid     = "SATC IOT";
const char* password = "IOT2023@";
int contador = 10;

// Inicializa Bot Telegram
#define BOTtoken "6429111560:AAEUDkKQkHJKbl1BjxeB10S8M02hsx6o0TA"  // bot token (botfather)
#define CHAT_ID "1178486300"

WiFiClientSecure client;

UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOTtoken, client);

void handleNewMessages(int numNewMessages) {
    for (int i=0; i<numNewMessages; i++) {
        // id de bate-papo
        String chat_id = String(bot.messages[i].chat_id);
        if (chat_id != CHAT_ID) {
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Usuario não autorizado", "");
            continue;
        }

        String text = bot.messages[i].text;

        if (text == "/comida") {
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Alimentando", "");
            abridor.write(90);
            delay(500);
            abridor.write(0);
            contador--;
        }
        if (contador >= 7) {
            digitalWrite(verde, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(amarelo, LOW);
            digitalWrite(vermelho, LOW);

        } else if (contador >= 4) {
            digitalWrite(verde, LOW);
            digitalWrite(amarelo, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(vermelho, LOW);

        } else {
            digitalWrite(verde, LOW);
            digitalWrite(amarelo, LOW);
            digitalWrite(vermelho, HIGH);
        }
    }
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    ESP32PWM::allocateTimer(0);
    abridor.setPeriodHertz(50);
    abridor.attach(servoPin, 1000, 2000);

    pinMode(verde, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(amarelo, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(vermelho, OUTPUT);

    abridor.attach(servoPin);  // vincular o servo no servoPin

    // Conecte-se à rede WiFi com SSID e senha
    Serial.print("Conectado a ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    client.setCACert(TELEGRAM_CERTIFICATE_ROOT);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    // IP local
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi conectado.");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, "Bot iniciado", "");
}

void loop() {
    int numNewMessages = bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1);

    while (numNewMessages) {
        handleNewMessages(numNewMessages);
        numNewMessages = bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1);
    }
}
```